# Syntastic autoclose when cursor change syntastic_loc_list_height

Tags: vim, syntastic

I know Syntastic has the settings variable `syntastic_auto_loc_list` with different options, but none of them is what I'm looking for.

What I want is a way to show the location list when there are errors in the current opened file, but autoclose after the cursor has moved. I do not want it to keep closing it everytime I open a file that has syntastic errors. It will be nice to just know that there are errors when I open the file, but as soon as I move the cursor, it would close.

Is there a way to do that?